# Array of arrays ? 4 ways linked matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, matrix, containers

I need to create an object that would represent a bi-dimensonnal array and have the following methods :

- `appendRow()`
- `appendColumn()`
- `removeRow(uint index)`
- `removeColumn(uint index)`

The last two methods makes me think that i should use linked nodes to avoid repeated copies of elements, but my problem is that this is a matrix, not a regular single dimension array, which makes it complicated.

Is there some kind of object i don't know the name of that would be capable of doing that kind of thing ? Just a name, then i'll search how to implementit myself.

I need to do that in JavaScript but it's ok if you point me to something written in another language.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `something written in another language` - I'm sure you want it for some *particular* purpose, so you should specify what languages are available.

Comment: I just meant that i would manage to understand what you point me. I need to to create an abstract representation of a keyboard for a keyboard editor made out of html/css/js.

Comment: XML might work. Most languages have DOM objects that would let you access what you need.

Comment: What do you mean by XML ? I have to possibilities to do what i want : manipulate the DOM using JavaScript (jQuery precisely) and then read it to determine a final abstract representation of my grid, or maintain and manipulate an abstract representation of that grid object and regenerate the HTML from it at every modification (which is want i want to do).

Comment: @Jeffman I see what you mean, but the DOM HTML table object only has these features for the rows, and i need both row and columns.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an object in javascript.

Maybe this library would be useful: https://github.com/mikolalysenko/ndarray.

Comment: Thanks i'm gonna have a look to this.

Comment: Check **Strided Arrays** in this article (also about this library) http://0fps.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-multidimensional-arrays-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at math.js, this library comes with extensive support for matrix manipulations.

http://mathjs.org